# For OAuth Clients, what bad things can happen if the client_secret is exposed?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

What harm could a nefarious user cause if they found the client_secret?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** It is a high level security breach

If you followed recent events like [Facebook breach](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/09/28/facebook-says-it-has-discovered-security-issue-affecting-nearly-50-million-accounts-investigation-in-early-stages.html), then we are talking the possibility of a similar threat. You are simply welcoming a malicious party to obtain access tokens, which they can used for anything.! Your OAuth token protected endpoints are now compromised.

[RFC6819 -  OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) under [Threat: Obtaining Client Secrets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.1) highlights below,

> The resulting impact would be the following:
>
> - Client authentication of access to the authorization server can be
>   bypassed.
> - Stolen refresh tokens or authorization "codes" can be replayed

If you are compare with a public client, which does not hold client credentials, special attack vector opens through [client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4). So even if refresh token or authorisation code is safe, malicious party can exploit the mentioned grant to obtain access tokens. So never ever expose client secret.